# How to use html special special characters as normal string

Tags: html

How to convert HTML special characters as normal string...

For example:

```
<h1>Copy Right Symbol &copf;</h1>
```

I want to print &copf as normal string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the & as

```
&amp;
```

So it would be

```
<h1>Copy Right Symbol &amp;copf;</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will display &copf

I will display &copf

I will display "&"copf

I will display &copf

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<p>I will display &#38;copf</p>
<p>I will display &#x26;copf</p>
<p>I will display "&"copf <p>
<p>I will display &amp;copf <p>

</body>
</html>